# Undefined offset 13 #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation

Tags: php

I wrote this function to convert numbers in string format like:
1234567 -> 1,234,567
but it id not work for utf-8, so I had to change it to:

```
    function format_string_number($num = '0') {
     if(strlen($num)<4) {
      $res = $num;
     }else{
      $arr = preg_split('//u', $num, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
      $res = "";
      for ($i=0; $i <= strlen($num) ; $i++) { 
       $res .= (string)$arr[$i];
       if(((strlen($num) - $i -1) % 3 == 0) AND ($i != strlen($num)-1)){
       $res .= ",";
      }
     }
    }
    return $res;
   }
```

but it does not work, please help me to find out where the problem is?

Comment: Change `<=` to `<`.

Comment: String indexes go from `0` to `strlen-1`, you're trying to access `$arr[strlen]`.

Comment: I think the problem is that I use utf-8 characters in my array but using strlen() function to determine the length. I guess there should be another function or another way to get the lenth.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `mb_strlen()`?

Comment: And use `mb_substr()` to access the characters, instead of `[$i]`.

Comment: But whatever you do, you have to use `<` instead of `<=` in the `for` loop. You're getting an undefined offset because you're indexing past the end of the string.